# repeat appendChild x times

Tags: javascript

I have this simple code wrapped inside a function:

```
slots = timeset / 2;
var oneslot = document.createElement("option");
document.getElementById('presentingslots').appendChild('oneslot');
```

the variable slots changes obviously. I want to appendChild oneslot x times where x = slots
How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `slots` is small, you can get away with appending each element in a loop:

```
slots = timeset / 2;
for (var i = 0; i < slots; i++) {
    var oneslot = document.createElement('option');
    document.getElementById('presentingslots').appendChild(oneslot);
}
```

If `slots` can be large, then you'll want use a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment):

```
slots = timeset / 2;
var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < slots; i++) {
    var oneslot = document.createElement('option');
    df.appendChild(oneslot);
}
document.getElementById('presentingslots').appendChild(df);
```

This will be more efficient since the DOM is only updated once.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
slots = timeset / 2;
for (var i = 0; i < slots; i += 1) {
  var oneslot = document.createElement("option");
  document.getElementById('presentingslots').appendChild('oneslot');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop (for, while) to do this.

```
slots = timeset / 2;
var presentingslots = document.getElementById('presentingslots');
for (var i = 0; i < slots; i++) {
  var oneslot = document.createElement('option'); 
  presentingslots.appendChild(oneslot);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple for loop would do the trick.  And you can set the value as well as the text that is shown.

```
var slots = timeset / 2,
    el = document.getElementById('presentingslots');
for (var i = 0; i < slots; i++) {
    var oneslot = document.createElement('option');
    oneslot.text = i;
    oneslot.value = 'set my value if you want';
    el.appendChild(oneslot);
}
```

[I made a simple jsFiddle to show.](http://jsfiddle.net/wk2uG/)